# How to find which part of text message has a nested link/and open it?

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, telethon

Example text message I received on telegram:

> *Listen to best music:* [Ava Max - My Head & My Heart](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w8mBplMtwJ8)

My question is, how can my script check the message and eventually open the site via nested link?
I tried:

```
      for entity in event.message.text:
            if isinstance(entity, MessageEntityTextUrl):
                open_url(entity.url)
```

but no luck - Script doesn't open the link.

**//Edit**
implemented **watzon**'s solution:

```
async def my_event_handler(event):
            msg = event.message.message
            for _, inner_text in msg.get_entities_text(MessageEntityTextUrl):
                    open_url(inner_text)
```

and now the error is:

```
...in my_event_handler
    for _, inner_text in msg.get_entities_text(MessageEntityTextUrl):
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get_entities_text'
```

I must have missed my mistake here, what should I change in the msg?

//Edit2

```
msg = event.message
```

fixed the error but I still don't get the link as output.

Comment: what is an `entity` here ? Can you print it and share that ? Because if .text if a string, then it is only one char

Comment: In your implementation of @watzon's answer, just define `msg` as `msg = event.message`. `event.message.message` is a string representation of the message, that's why it has no attribute `'get_entities_text'`.

Comment: @druskacik thank you very much, the error does not appear anymore but the next problem is that the _inner_text_ is actually the nested link *visible text*, not the link I can open.
So looking at the example with Ava Max song above, my output is:
**"Ava Max - My Head & My Heart"** BUT should be **youtube.com/....**
  
How can I achieve this? is MessageEntityTextUrl used in the correct way here?

Comment: Will you please check whether the variable `_` contains the url? You could rewrite it like `for url, inner_text in msg.get_entities_text(MessageEntityTextUrl):
                    open_url(url)`

Comment: @druskacik so simple yet so good, thank you! '_' contained offset, length, url etc. of the Message entity so I used openURL(`_.url`) and now it does, indeed, open a nested link. There are other issues as far as I checked some cases but I think we are done here on this problem. Thank you so much.

Comment: No problem. If your problem is solved, please accept my or the other answer so that users see this question as solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct implementation of @watzon's answer would look something like this:

```py
from telethon.tl.types import MessageEntityTextUrl

async def my_event_handler(event):
    msg = event.message
    for url_entity, inner_text in msg.get_entities_text(MessageEntityTextUrl):
        url = url_entity.url
        open_url(url)
        ...
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be using [message.get_entities_text()](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/modules/custom.html?highlight=entities#telethon.tl.custom.message.Message.get_entities_text).

Example:

```py
for _, inner_text in message.get_entities_text(MessageEntityTextUrl):
  open_url(inner_text)
```

Alternatively you can leave out the filter argument and loop over all of the provided entities, but given your example code this should work in place.

Comment: Thank you for a really quick answer. I implemented your solution and got the 'No attribute' error, could you please tell me whats the correct way of defining a message var? (msg in my case).

Comment: @RektLeft what was the error? You should be able to get the message from the event. Normally you'd be using `@client.on(events.NewMessage)` to decorate a method, and that method would have an `event` argument. In this case, `event.message` would give you the message that triggered the event.