# How to extract link from hyperlink in message with telethon?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telegram-bot, telethon

I am trying to extract the links from the hyperlinked texts, to be able to put them at the end of the message, and finally to remove the hyperlinks.

I tried to do it like this:

```
def extract_link(event):
    event.message.message = event.message.message + "\nSources :"
    for entity in event.message:
        if isinstance(entity, MessageEntityTextUrl):
            print(entity.url)
            event.message.message = event.message.message + "\n- " + entity.url
    event.message.entity = None
```

But i have this error :
Error: 'Message' object is not iterable

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This question is a possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/70281439/.

Answer (score 4):

Use this code, this will help you!

```
from telethon import TelegramClient, sync, events
from telethon.tl.types import MessageEntityTextUrl

api_id = 
api_hash = ''

client = TelegramClient('session', api_id, api_hash)

@client.on(events.NewMessage(chats=-1001675261848))
async def my_event_handler(event):
    msg = event.message
    for url_entity, inner_text in msg.get_entities_text(MessageEntityTextUrl):
        url = url_entity.url
        print(url)


client.start()
client.run_until_disconnected()
```